# paste numeric to numeric

Tags: r, merge, paste, radix

I simply need to merge (like a plait?) to elements that contain numeric values. I know I can `past()`, but I need to the number to  stay as numeric.

```
x <- 1:2; x
# [1] 1 2
y <- c(9999, 9999); y
# [1] 9999 9999    
z <- [some function]; z
# [1] 1 9999 2 9999          # my desired output
class(z)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: do you mean `c(x,y)`?

Comment: @mtoto, thanks for the prompt response. I believe  `c(x,y)` would give me `1    2 9999 9999`, like back to back. I need something like `paste-braiding-as.numeric`

Comment: another option: `c(rbind(x,y))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map`,

```
unlist(Map(c, x, y))
#[1]    1 9999    2 9999

str(unlist(Map(c, x, y)))
# num [1:4] 1 9999 2 9999
class(unlist(Map(c, x, y)))
#[1] "numeric"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `matrix()`:

```
c(matrix(c(x,y), ,2, byrow=TRUE))
```